# Derivative of standard gaussian hypergeometric function $_2F_1$

Tags: derivatives

I have a very simple question on the first derivative of a standard guassian hypergeometric function.

When I input the following command

D[Hypergeometric2F1[x, a, b, c], x]

Mathematica returns

$Hypergeometric2F1^{(0,1,0,0)}[x, a, b, c]$

Could anyone tell me what the above hypergeometric function means, especially the superscript?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Derivative of the function  wrt $a$, I guess.

Comment: I agree. Are you sure you want to differentiate $$\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(a,b;c;x\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{n!(c)_n} x^n $$ with respect to the first parameter ($a$)?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to differentiate it wrt the first parameter (a). Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, the final target is to show the hypergeometric function is an increasing function of the first parameter. So I'd like to differentiate it wrt the first parameter a. Do you have any other solutions to show this?

Answer (score 1):

According to K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Ch. 60, Springer,

$$\frac{d}{dx}~_2F_1(a,b;c;x)=\frac{ab}{c}~_2F_1(a+1,b+1;c+1;x)\\
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}~_2F_1(a,b;c;x)=\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}~_2F_1(a+n,b+n;c+n;x)
$$

where $(a)_n$ is the Pochhammer polynomial, of course.

Comment: This should be easily established via series.

Comment: But I'd like to differentiate it wrt the first parameter a. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @JunyuLiu Be that as it may, the Mathematica code you wrote was D[Hypergeometric2F1[x, a, b, c], x] (differentiation w.r.t. $x$). Given the nature of the Pochhammer polynomials, I would think you will be limited to cases where closed form solutions are available, such as $F(a,b;c;1), which can be expressed in terms of gamma functions.